# not receiving JSON from php with getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

I am trying to pass an array to the browser using php and jquery but I the when I try to use the 'data' returned from php's encode_json, it comes up undefined.  I'm just learning php, jquery, and json and so far haven't found very good documentation on alot of this stuff, especially json, even in the books I have.  Thanks in advance!

Here is a stripped down version of the jquery I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jsonResult;//I will want to be able to use the data in other functions

    $.getJSON("json.php", function(data){  
        jsonResult = data;
        var str;
        var nuts = [203,204,205,207];

        str = '<p>' + data[nuts[0]].NutraDesc + '</p>';
        $('#stuff').html(str);
        }
    );
});
```

This is the php:

```
    include_once 'databasePHP.php';
        $json_tst = $db->query( "SELECT  def.Nutr_No, NutrDesc, Nutr_Val, Units 
                FROM nutr_def as def  JOIN nut_data as data  ON def.Nutr_No = data.Nutr_No 
                WHERE data.NDB_No = 1001 LIMIT 0, 2");

        $food = array();

        while($row = $json_tst->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
           $Nutr_No = $row['Nutr_No'];
           $food[$Nutr_No][] = array(
               'NutrDesc' => $row['NutrDesc'],
               'Nutr_Val' => $row['Nutr_Val'],
               'Units' => $row['Units']
           );
        };

        echo  json_encode($food);
?>
```

which returns this json which I checked on jsonlint.com and it said it was valid:

```
 {"203":[{"NutrDesc":"Protein","Nutr_Val":"0.85","Units":"g"}],"204":[{"NutrDesc":"Total lipid (fat)","Nutr_Val":"81.11","Units":"g"}]}
```

Comment: The thing that immediately jumps out to me is possibly a typo.  You're looking for `data[nuts[0]].NutraDesc` but it's called `NutrDesc` in the JSON and PHP you showed us.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that!  Unfortunately it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because the numbers should be strings. Try to add quotes around the numbers in nuts, like this:

```
var nuts = ["203","204","205","207"];
```

The following probably works as well:

```
str = '<p>' + data[String(nuts[0])].NutraDesc + '</p>';
```

Also, have you tried adding `console.log(data);` to the getJSON function to make sure it receives the JSON?

**EDIT:** 
Here is a working JSFiddle from your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/rKLqM/

Things that were wrong:

- you weren't parsing the result as JSON (`JSON.parse`)
- `NutraDesc` was spelled wrong
- You didn't convert the numbers to strings
- You needed to add [0] to the jsonResult because there's an extra array within it (see the [])

Comment: I added the console.log and it returned this (the data was inside the array):                                                         Object
203: Array[1]
204: Array[1]
__proto__: Object

Comment: I updated my answer with some working code for you, check the link :)

Comment: A good advice would be to log every step you do when something goes wrong. The result in the console indicates everything works except for the parsing, so then try to log individual variables in order to narrow down where the problem lies. Also; in a JSON result curly brackets mean objects and square brackets mean arrays, so to access `bar` in `var foobar = {"var" : ["foo", "bar"] }` you'd use `foobar["var"][1]`. Good luck!

Comment: I could have had three days of my life back if I would have posted this question earlier!  Thanks!! It was the extra [0] that finally did it.  Do you happen to have a suggestion on the subject (especially JSON)?

Comment: Glad I could be of help! Perhaps a good start would be to learn more about JavaScript arrays and objects (and iterating through them using a `for loop`), because JSON consists of those. As for logging: try going a step back if you don't get the desired result. If `console.log(data[nuts[0]].NutraDesc` returns `undefined`, try `console.log(data[nuts[0]])` and see what that returns.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript object property can be accessed with `obj["propName"]`

So, change

```
var nuts = [203,204,205,207];
```

to

```
var nuts = ["203","204","205","207"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Either use this or my String(nuts[0]) suggestion, along with the hint @Archer gave: "You're looking for data[nuts[0]].NutraDesc but it's called NutrDesc in the JSON and PHP you showed us."

Comment: I've changed the array to include the quotes (which is good to know!) and tried using String(nuts[0]) but unfortunately neither worked.  I really thought the typo that Shankar mentioned would solve it, but it still prints 'undefined' to the screen.

Comment: See my updated answer for some working code. Simply remove the `var data = "long-json-string-here";` line